# Is there a ubuntu remote keyboard app?

Tags: keyboard, ubuntu-touch, touchpad, remote

I want to use a BQ M10 and a nexus4 together as a convergance desktop system. But can't find any app that can turn the nexus into a bluetooth or wifi remote keyboard/touchpad.. This way i can travel ultra light. And enables me to use destop mode without having to drag a fullsize keyboard along all the time. I really expected this to exist, but it's nowhere to be found.

Comment: Why not just buy one of those mini Bluetooth keyboards? They have much less lag than a phone connected to a tablet with an app, and they're still very light. And the Nexus 4's screen is pretty small. Are you sure that would even work as a keyboard?

Comment: Something like this appears to exist for Maemo devices: https://wiki.maemo.org/Bluemaemo but I haven't found anything for other operating systems.

Comment: @Zacharee1 I have a BT keyboard, but I want to get rid of it. The idea is to travel light, I use a Nexus Phone, and i have a BQ M10.  Touch desktop really NEEDS an external keyboard to be functional. So the moment you need the desktop mode, and you don't have a BT keyboard at hand, BUT you have a NEXUS4 with Ubuntu....  Well...  Why isn't there a keyboard app???    :-)  It would just make A LOT of sense if Canonical would make the on screen keyboard in Touch capable of being used over Wifi or BT.